# joose/javascript based mason2 like server side templates

Tags: node.js, mason, joose

Exists something like [Perlish Mason2](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.14/lib/Mason/Manual.pod) templates for the node.js? Mean something with the following functionality:

- [component](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.14/lib/Mason/Manual/Components.pod) based architecture (!!!) (with autohandlers, dhandlers (Base.mc))
- on the fly compiling sources (components) into full featured [joose (javascript) objects](http://joose.it/)
- plugins (caching and etc..)